# SQL - Update multiple cells in one columns with the same ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `Answer` in SQL Server like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdKQ2.png

Because the `AnswerID` is an auto-increment and I don't know exactly its value when running the query.

So how can I update the `AnswerContent` column?

Example: I need to update

- `"Leopard - False"` to `"Elephant - True"`
- `"Tiger - True"` to `"Tiger - False"`

Thank you.

--- Update ---

I cannot change the table structure because it's my teacher's order.

Comment: the problem is I cannot call to specific AnswerID

Comment: sure you can!.....Otherwise search for the string to be updated in contents column.....

Comment: Look-up the syntax for the UPDATE command. [This](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) might be a good place to start. HINT: You don't have to use `AnswerID` in your WHERE clause - you can use something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one shot using the [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) expression. Here is an example:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET
    AnswerContent = CASE
        WHEN AnswerContent='Leopard' AND IsTrue='False` THEN `Elephant`
        ELSE AnswerContent -- Keep the value unchanged
    END
,   IsTrue = ... -- Do other columns using the same expression structure
```